# Hangfire JobCancellationToken throws immediately after calling method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I would like to use the cancellation tokens as described by the official documentation https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html

However after calling a method by passing `JobCancellationToken.Null` the token seems to be cancelled immediately because an exception is thrown by `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`
Without the cancellation token logic in place the long running method runs smoothly.

My architecture looks like this:

**BackgroundService.cs**

```
public class BackgroundService : IBackgroundService
{
    private readonly IBackgroundJobClient client;

    public BackgroundService(IBackgroundJobClient client)
    {
        this.client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    }

    public async Task<string> EnqueueTaskAsync(string id)
    {
        string jobId = client.Enqueue<ITaskService>(x => x.ProcessAsync(id, JobCancellationToken.Null));

        await Task.CompletedTask;

        return jobId;
    }
}
```

**TaskService.cs**

```
public class TaskService : ITaskService
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public TaskService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<TaskService>() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        this.mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
    }

    public async Task ProcessAsync(string id, IJobCancellationToken ct)
    {
        var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct.ShutdownToken);

        cts.Token.Register(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled taskId: " + id + " " + DateTime.Now);
        });

        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // ...
    }
}
```

**using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**

```
services.AddTransient<ITaskService, TaskService>();
services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundService, BackgroundService>();
```

**Console logging output**

```
[12:15:16 WRN] Creating a job based on method `ProcessAsync`...
[12:15:16 WRN] Job `269` state `` was unapplied.
[12:15:16 WRN] Job `269` state was changed from `` to `Enqueued`
[12:15:16 WRN] Job that is based on method `ProcessAsync` has been created with id `269`
[12:15:26 WRN] Job `269` state `Enqueued` was unapplied.
[12:15:26 WRN] Job `269` state was changed from `Enqueued` to `Processing`
[12:15:26 WRN] Starting to perform job `269`
Cancelled taskId: d3c56cc1-3cfb-45d7-bba3-ff486fd4aa99 25/10/2019 12:15:26
[12:15:26 WRN] Job `269` has been performed
```

**Versions used**

- .NET Core 2.2
- HangFire.Core 1.7.7
- Hangfire.AspNetCore 1.7.7
- Hangfire.LiteDB 0.2.1

Any suggestions what could cause this behavior?